# jQuery: How can I tell when a tab/window gains focus

Tags: jquery, focus, onfocus

Is there an event that I can register for that fires each time the user clicks on a tab, meaning that they were on my page's tab, clicked on another tab, then came back to my tab.

**EDIT:**
By tabs, I mean browser tabs, not jQueryUI tabs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Matijis provided this answer in a comment, but I wanted to accept it so here it is as an answer.

```
$(window).on('focus', function() { // your code });
```

Comment: Tab lost focus: `$(window).on('blur', function() { // your code });`

Answer (score 2):

Try using jquery $(selector).focusin or :focus, they both work quite the same way.

http://api.jquery.com/focusin/

http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

Comment: Look at his Q: EDIT: By tabs, I mean browser tabs, not jQueryUI tabs.

Comment: So then can I just do `document.focusin = function () { stuff }` ?

Comment: `$(window).on('focus', function() { // your code });` should do the trick

Comment: @Matijis that works great! Put that in an answer and I'll accept.