# How to create an event while browser page gets switched to my website tab like chat box status changes in gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

In my webpage there is online status like *available,idle,busy etc*.If we didn't load  the page until 10 minutes the status get changed to available to idle.Once i return back to my webpage tab browser, how can create an event that used to change status idle to available unless refreshing the page.

Comment: Research keywords: [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/), `visibilitychange` event.

Comment: and for older than IE10 I think you can use `window.onfocus` and `window.onblur`

Comment: Wanted to add as an answer but doesn't really make sense to post something which was already discussed on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993157/visibilitychange-event-is-not-triggered-when-switching-program-window-with-altt) (read the OP completely). Other related: [How can I tell when a tab/window gains focus](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9365576/1369473) and [Detect If Browser Tab Has Focus](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7389328/1369473)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using the mouseover event on the body element.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
   // If idle then set status to available

});
```

EDIT:

Here's an idea. The Window.requestAnimationFrame() function is only executed when the tab/window is active. So if the function is not called, that means the user is not viewing the tab or the tab is not active.

Check this example. Run the script, then switch tabs for a few seconds, then switch back

```js
var isTabOpen=true;
var tabTimer=null;



function tabCheck(){
  //This function is only called when the tab is open.
  
  if(tabTimer) clearTimeout(tabTimer);
  
    tabTimer = setTimeout(function(){
      isTabOpen = false;
    },1000);
  
  isTabOpen=true;
   
}

setInterval(function(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(tabCheck);
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += (isTabOpen+'<br/>');
},1000);
```

Comment: This can be done only if i mouse over on the webpage body.i need event should execute while selecting the broweser tab.